# Question on solving the Schrödinger for hydrogen atom

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm following this solution to the Schrödinger equation for hydrogen atom:

http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/237/hatom.php

The derivation proceeds to separate the angular and radial parts, and arrives at this sum of terms:

$$
\bbox[pink]{\frac{1}{R}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}r}\left(r^2\frac{{\rm d}R}{{\rm d}r}\right)}+\bbox[lightblue]{\frac{1}{Y\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial Y}{\partial\theta}\right)+\frac{1}{Y\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2Y}{\partial\phi^2}}+\bbox[pink]{\frac{2\mu r^2}{\hbar^2}\left(E+\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\right)}=0\qquad. $$

Then it is said:

"The first and fourth terms depend on
only, the middle terms depend on the angles only. **They can only balance each other for all points in space if the radial and angular terms are the same constant but with opposite sign.**"

I don't understand why the bolded line is true. Why is it that two functions of different variables whose sum is zero must be equal to the same constant (except the minus sign on the other)?

Comment: If $f(x) = g(y)$ then, taking partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ gives $f'(x) = 0,$ i.e. $f(x) = c$ for some constant $c$. In the same way we get $g'(y) = 0,$ i.e. $g(y) = d$ for some constant $d$. But then $c = f(x) = g(y) = d,$ i.e. $f$ and $g$ are both constant and equal to the same constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a technique called separation of variables. We'll look at a simpler example case.

Suppose we know that $f(x) + g(y) = 0$. Then we know that $f(0) + g(y) = 0$ for all $y$, so therefore $g(y) = -f(0)$ which is a constant.

In general, if a bunch of functions that each depend on different variables add to zero, then they are all constants.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let's rewrite the equation as \begin{equation}f(r)+g(\theta)=0\end{equation} The key insight here is that (1) holds for all $r$ and $\theta$.  So pick your favorite value of $r$, say, $r_0$ and let $f(r_0)=\lambda$.

By definition, $\lambda$ is a constant.  But now substitute $r=r_0$ into (1): for any $\theta$, $$0=\lambda+g(\theta)$$  Solving for $g(\theta)$, we see that $g$ is constant.

The same argument shows that $f$ is constant too.